# @NamedQuery select parameter meaning

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

Found some examples of @NamedQuery annotations,e.g.:

```
@NamedQuery(name="employeeBySsn" query="select e from Employee e where e.ssn = :ssn")
```

what does parameter **e** mean?

the second usage of it seems like alias name of table and what does *"select e"* part mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is same as using "Select * " in the normal sql... here 'e' represents the reference to the class...

Answer (score 0):

It is like select * from table
You are saying you need all fields of Employee entity object

Answer (score 0):

e is not the alias name.It is similar to an reference to the table Employee. So that e.ssn means you are accessing the ssn field of the refernce e.